# Oracle SQL how to get rowmax?

Tags: sql, oracle

I likely lack the correct vocabulary, which is why my google searches were unsuccessful to achieve the following `rowmax` type of operation: I want to create a new column that is for each row the maximum of two existing columns and is bounded by 0.

```
SELECT a,b, rowmax(a,b,0) as c
FROM ...
```

Comment: What is the desired value of `c` if `a` or `b` (or both) is/are `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `greatest()`:

```
greatest(a, b, 0) as c
```